# Track completed downloads from glassfish

Tags: servlets, glassfish, download

I want to be able to track completed downloads served by my glassfish server. I couldn't find a 100% correct solution using servlet life cycle listeners.
Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Track this question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524487/browser-download-complete-event>

Answer (score 1):

Put a `try-catch` on `IOException` while serving the file download. If it's thrown, then serving the file download has failed.

E.g. in a custom file servlet:

```
try {
    response.getOutputStream().write(...);

    // Success!
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Fail!

    throw e;
}
```

Or in a servlet filter which is mapped on the appropriate URL pattern matching file downloads:

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    // Success!
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Fail!

    throw e;
}
```