# Triggering a script when a download finishes (or starts)

Tags: javascript, download

I'm working on a script that inputs data into a web form, hits a button to download a file, and repeats that until it's downloaded a set of files. At present, I've been manually triggering the script every time a file downloads, which is inconvenient because it's often a large set of files. I would like the script to check when a download finishes (or starts), and submit the form to ask for the next download at that point.

My understanding is that there's no browser event on download start ([Browser download complete event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524487/browser-download-complete-event)), although all the sources I could find were at least 5 years old and that may have changed.

I've seen many similar questions that are being asked from the perspective of someone on the server's side; since this is entirely client-side, I'm asking in the hopes that there's a kludge that's available as a result.

Comment: What are you looking for, an event when a download starts or finishes? You're talking about both in your question like they're synonyms...

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my question about downloads finishing but the previous questions I saw were asking about download start. On reflection, I can use either.

Comment: the browser won't help you, but maybe you can open a 2nd connection to the server and have it provide a progress of how much it's shipped...